# How to extend vbscript with C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I would like to extend the functionality of vbscript with the code I have written in c#. I have written some classes to automate the SAP GUI and would like to use these classes in all the vbscript files I have.

I have hundreds of vbscript files and know it will take years to convert all them to C#. So I think it will be faster to expose my c# classes to vbscript.

Do you know how to do this or know any references online I can study?

Comment: Use the [ComVisible] attribute to expose C# code to vbscript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you're running your VBScript from the command-line or from within something like Office.

If the former, you could create one or more command-line apps that you can call from any scripting language and into which you pass parameters & action specifiers just like any other command-line tool. (Also consider moving to PowerShell in this case - it exponentially better than VBScript for command-line scripting & has great integration with .NET).

If the latter, you'll likely need to register your C# classes using RegAsm and then create instances of your C# types as per any other COM type. See this post for more details: [How do I call .NET code (C#/vb.net) from vbScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357440/how-do-i-call-net-code-c-vb-net-from-vbscript)

Answer (score 1):

VB **script** runs on the client inside the browser run-time.

The only C# solution I am aware of to run inside the browser, is silverlight. It is still just c# though.

You can access c# code from scripting languages like VB- of java-script, by decorating them with the `[ScriptableMember]` attribute, like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Members that can be called from javascript. (or vbscript)
/// </summary>
public sealed class LINEARVIEWER_SL_SCRIPTS {

    [ScriptableMember]
    public void ChangeNetwork(string pNetworkFilterId, string pNetworkFilter) {

        MainViewModel MainVM = (MainViewModel)((MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual).DataContext;

        long SectionID;

        if (long.TryParse(pNetworkFilterId, out SectionID) == false) {
            throw new FormatException("'" + pNetworkFilterId + "' not a valid section / network ID.");
        }

        MainVM.RoadFilterViewModel.SelectSectionAsync(SectionID, /* completed handler = */ null);
    }
}
```

You have to register these classes when the silverligh (c#) application starts up, like so:

```
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {

            ...

            HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("LINEARVIEWER_SL_SCRIPTS", new LINEARVIEWER_SL_SCRIPTS());
        }
```

From the java (or vb) script, you can then simply call those methods like so:

```
    function DoAddToLIV(pNetworkFilterId, pNetworkFilter) {
        ...
        gObjLIV.Content.LINEARVIEWER_SL_SCRIPTS.ChangeNetwork(pNetworkFilterId, pNetworkFilter);
        ...
    }
```

where `gObjLIB.Content` is the id of the silverlight object inside the html page.

```
    var gObjLIV = null;

    function onSilverlightPluginLoaded(sender, args) {

        gObjLIV = sender.getHost();
    }
```

You can hook that function to the silverlight object in the html of ASPX page, using this parameter:

```
<param name="onLoad" value="onSilverlightPluginLoaded" />
```

Let me know if I missed anything or if you need more examples. I don't mind.