# Accessing TFS database using Vbscript

Tags: api, vbscript, tfs

I have been assigned the task of creating a web dashboard with information I retrieve from a TFS database using the available API.  Ideally I would like to create this using Vbscript as I have existing code that could easily be reused, however I am unsure if there is away of connecting to the database using VBScript, any ideas if this is achievable??

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit vbscript seems like a strange choice. That said, given the TFS API (the Object Model) is a .NET assembly then as long as you can call the methods properly from your VBScript code you should be OK.

As for calling .NET from VBScript have a look at this question: [How do I call .NET code (C#/vb.net) from vbScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357440/how-do-i-call-net-code-c-vb-net-from-vbscript)

Comment: Thanks, will look into that. An alternative approach I am considering could be to use Visual Basic to connect to the database, save the record set then open the record set in my script, would this work??

Comment: If you can save your record set as comma separated values (CSV) then you could use really any script on that result.

Comment: Is there any documentation on saving a workitemtype as a csv, or any examples, new to c# so not completely sure